# Java: QuickSort on LinkedList gives me exception

Tags: java, linked-list, quicksort

I'm studying for exam (Algorithms and data structures), and I'm trying to make `quicksort` work for `LinkedList` but it's giving me `ListIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For homework a while ago, I used `straightinsertion` for sorting `ArrayList` and `Vector`, now I'd like to understand `QuickSor`t (I do in theory) for `LinkedList`.
I'm not too familiar with `linkedlist`, but it shouldn't be too different from `ArrayList`?

```
public class Sort {

public static void quickSort(LinkedList<Oseba> a) {
    sort(a, 0, a.size() - 1); // this is line 16
}

public static void sort(LinkedList<Oseba> a, int l, int r) {
    int i = l;
    int j = r;

    Oseba x = a.get((l + r) / 2), w;

    do {
        while (a.get(i).mlajsi(x)) {
            ++i;
        }
        while (x.mlajsi(a.get(j))) { // this is line 31
            --j;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            w = a.get(i);
            a.set(i, a.get(j));
            a.set(j, w);
            ++i;
            --j;
        }
    } while (i <= j);

    if (l < j) {
        sort(a, l, j);
    }

    if (i < r) {
        sort(a, i, r);
    }
}
}
```

`Oseba` means 'a Person', it's a class I made for testing various methods (like sorting, comparing)

```
public class Oseba implements Comparable<Oseba> {

protected String priimekIme; //surnameName
protected int letoRojstva; //year of birth
protected Spol spol; //gender (enum)

public Oseba(String priimekIme, int letoRojstva, Spol spol) {
    this.priimekIme = priimekIme;
    this.letoRojstva = letoRojstva;
    this.spol = spol;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Oseba o) {
    if (this.letoRojstva < o.letoRojstva) {
        return -1;
    } else if (this.letoRojstva > o.letoRojstva) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return this.priimekIme.compareTo(o.priimekIme);
    }
}

public boolean mlajsi(Oseba o) { //younger
    return (o.letoRojstva - this.letoRojstva <= 0);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = priimekIme + ", " + spol.getKratko() + ", " + letoRojstva;
    return s;
}
}
```

And this is an error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: -1, Size: 6
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:553)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:474)
    at javaapplication1.Sort.sort(Sort.java:31)
    at javaapplication1.Sort.quickSort(Sort.java:16)
    at javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:55)
Java Result: 1
```

This `quicksort` method is supposed to work with `Vector` or `ArrayList`, I don't know why it wouldn't with `LinkedList`?

Thanks!

Comment: This might not be the cause, but your "younger" method doesn't look right to me... If Adam and Bob are the same age, your method would say that they are both younger than each other (adam.younger(bob) and bob.younger(adam) would both be true). I think that "<=0" should just be "< 0" ?

Comment: Yes, that fixed it... ugh, I had a problem with static comparing methods too, i thought I fixed that.

Comment: Do you realize that the way you're implementing this, you've turned an `O(NlogN)` algorithm into `O(N^2 log N)`?

Comment: I did not realize that, would you tell me exactly why this is so? The quicksort algorithm is taken from my professor, just modified to use with linkedlist.

Answer (score 1):

Well you don't check for boundaries during your loops.

```
   while (a.get(i).mlajsi(x)) {
        ++i;
    }
    while (x.mlajsi(a.get(j))) { // this is line 31
        --j;
    }
```

should be

```
   while (i <= r && a.get(i).mlajsi(x)) {
        ++i;
    }
    while (j >= l && x.mlajsi(a.get(j))) { // this is line 31
        --j;
    }
```

and

```
} while (i <= j);
```

strictly speaking, should also take account that `i` and `j` are inside the boundaries (but i think it is not neccessary).
It will solve the exception issue, but I didn't verify the correctness of the algorithm.

Comment: That didn't seem to help, now I get `StackOverFlowError` on last line of code `sort(a, i, r)`

Answer (score 0):

One of the [big rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Introduction.2C_Chapter_1) in Java (and OO in general) is "code to interfaces, not to implementations." Right now, you're coding to the `LinkedList` implementation of the `List` interface. The only way to guarantee that this code will work with any List (`Vector`, `ArrayList`, etc.) is to change your declarations. For instance:

```
public static void quickSort(LinkedList<Oseba> a) {
```

Should become

```
public static void quickSort(List<Oseba> a) {
```

And similarly with sort:

```
public static void sort(List<Oseba> a, int l, int r) {
```

Now, whenever you declare a person, it should look like this:

```
List<Oseba> a = LinkedList<Oseba>();
```

But in the place of `LinkedList`, you can substitute any other type of list.

This doesn't answer the question of why your code is failing -- I think UmNyobe's advice is good, though I didn't test it -- but it answers your lesser question as to why this code isn't acting like other list types. It's because you're coding to the implementation, where you should be using the interface.

Comment: Yes yes, I knew that, it was like this before, I changed from List to LinkedList thinking it had anything to do with an error, of course it didn't. Thanks though.

Comment: @Issak - No worries. I've made similar moves when I'm flailing on a problem. After a while you just want to throw everything at it. :)